# Find and replace text in matrix

Tags: regex, string, r, replace, gsub

I have a character matrix filled with values that follow these general formats: `A/-`, `A/B`, `I/A`, `/`, `A/`, `/A`, `-/B`, `A/B/C`, `A/-/C`.

I need to clean this data set so all that remains are values that follow the format `A/B`, in other words, two single characters separated by a forward slash. Anything that contains a `-`, `I`, multiple forward slashes, a single forward slash with no letters, or a single forward slash with only one letter must be replaced with blanks "".

I have tried numerous iterations of `gsub()` to replace any values not fitting the proper format with "".

This is the closest I have found that makes sense to me, but it only gets rid of values containing `-`, `I`, multiple forward slashes, and a single forward slash (no surrounding letters). Data that remain are in the format `A/B` (the one I want to keep),  `A/`, `/B` (the other ones that need to be replaced):

```
    data.matrix = as.matrix(data)
    data.matrix.clean = gsub("/./|^/.|./$|^/$|-|I", "", data.matrix)
```

Perhaps I should write this differently without separating each of my independent criteria with a `|`? From what I've read, the `^` is to signify the beginning of a string and the `$` is to signify the end of a string. It seems to work in the `^/$` case, but not in the `^/.` or `./$` case and I'm not sure why.

After I try something new, I check to see what format all forward slash containing  values are in, using this code which seems to work fine.

```
slash = grep("/", data.matrix.clean)
slash.t = data.matrix.clean[slash]
table(slash.t)
```

Any help in better understanding symbols that can be used within `gsub()` to make this work properly would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I’ve removed the tags from the title [as per the guideline](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/1968).

Comment: Do you want to keep `"A/B/C"`?

Comment: No, I do not want to keep A/B/C. Trying some of the suggestions out now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the quantifier `*` (*any number of*) to replace the whole string:

```
data.matrix <- matrix(c("A/-", "A/B", "I/A", "/", "A/", "/A", 
                        "-/B", "A/B/C", "A/-/C"), ncol = 3)

     [,1]  [,2] [,3]   
[1,] "A/-" "/"  "-/B"  
[2,] "A/B" "A/" "A/B/C"
[3,] "I/A" "/A" "A/-/C"


sub(".*/.*/.*|^/.*|.*/$|^/$|.*-.*|.*I.*", "", data.matrix)

     [,1]  [,2] [,3]
[1,] ""    ""   ""  
[2,] "A/B" ""   ""  
[3,] ""    ""   ""
```

Comment: Thank you, this works exactly like I need it to. I had tried variations that included "*" before, but they never quite worked out for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`grepl`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) and replace the rest:

```
conforming = grepl('^(?!I)\\w/(?!I)\\w$', matrix, perl = TRUE)
matrix[! conforming] = ""
```

Literally, this reads:

The string starts with a character (except `I`), followed by a slash and a character (except `I`) and ends there.